# belong_to not working ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

I have created two tables in my db. The first table is `users`, with columns:

```
id, name
```

The second table is `microposts`, with columns:

```
id, content, user_id
```

This is my `Micropost` model

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :content, length: { maximum:20 }
end
```

and this is the index method in my `MicropostController`

```
def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
end
```

when I check in index view like this

```
<%= debug @microposts %>
```

I get this result

```
---
- !ruby/object:Micropost
  attributes:
    id: 1
    content: new micropost
    user_id: 1
    created_at: 2014-04-12 10:56:04.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-04-12 10:56:04.000000000 Z
```

I am not getting user table data with relation. How can i do this?

This is the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :micropost
end
```

Comment: it should be  has_many :microposts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the user who has the `micropost`, you should use `micropost.user`. For example: `@microposts.first.user` will return the user of @microposts's first record.

Comment: Thanks you are write but i have still query when i write down this in view <%= debug @microposts %> in this there is not display user data why

Comment: How to print full array in rails debug is not print full array

Comment: The `debug` method only returns a YAML representation of object, while your `micropost` object only has it's user's id(`user_id`) but not a `user` object. See more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html#method-i-debug)

Comment: then how can i debug full array ?

Comment: And I'm sorry for that I don't know whether there's some way to display an ActiveRecord with it's relation.